# Rails 5 - using synthetic attributes in queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I'm not sure if synthetic attributes are capable of being used this way, but I have an account model with two boolean fields, :is_class_accout and :is_expense_account.

I created a an attribute which is not persisted in teh db called :is_synthetic which return true if either :is_class_account is true or :is_expense_account is true.

What I want to do is write a query like:

Account.find_by_project_id(project_id).where(is_synthetic: true)

This returns a PG error because the resulting query is looking for the is_synthetic field in the db, and of course it's not there.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this expected behavior?

The code I am using is:

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
attribute :is_synthetic, :boolean
def is_synthetic
 self.is_class_account || self.is_expense_account
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour is expected. Two things here:

1. The example query is wrong since *find_by_project_id* would return the first matching Account record and not a collection to call *where* on.
2. In your case all you have to do is retrieve the Account records and then filter them:

   ```
   class Account < ApplicationRecord
     def is_synthetic
       self.is_class_account || self.is_expense_account
     end
   end

   # Returns an Array of accounts
   Account.where(project_id: <queried_project_id>).select(&:is_synthetic)
   ```